# make edges of donut curvy

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have [donut chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gjA73/). I want to make the edge of donut to be curvy as the image shows [image]. I tried to use this code to achieve what I want but I can't.

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
        .outerRadius(outerRadius)
        .startAngle(0);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `stroke-linejoin` to `round` for the generated path?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff The little arc segment is a closed, filled area `<path>`, not a thick curve.

Comment: @TimothyShields Still works if you stroke the path: http://jsfiddle.net/h9XNz/99/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Looks like the asker is wanting half-circles on the end of the arc, not slightly-rounded corners.

Comment: In any case, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177985/svg-rounded-corner) should help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [cornerRadius](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/aff9e559c5c9968b7ac6) property of d3.svg.arc(), added in D3 v3.5

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius)
    .cornerRadius(outerRadius - innerRadius)
    .startAngle(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxnymj28/1/

Comment: cornerRadius is a bit buggy, I don't know if that is because of d3 or just how SVGs work. It glitches out if you have an arc approaching 360 degrees or something like 1 degree.

Answer (score 2):

The `d3.svg.arc()` generator assumes you are giving it a single `datum`, not a list `data`. It therefore assumes that each of `startAngle`, `endAngle`, `innerRadius`, `outerRadius` is either a constant or a function of the single `datum`.

You cannot directly make the ends of the arc rounded over using this generator.

You could, however, draw two circles over the endpoints of the arc, using `arc.centroid(startAngle)` and `arc.centroid(endAngle)` as their centers and `(outerRadius-innerRadius)/2` as their radius. This will give you the rounded-over appearance.

Documentation: [`arc.centroid`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#arc_centroid)

Comment: I did as you said check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjA73/2/). But I can't get transition for second circle.

Comment: You seem to be animating the text with no problems. Just animate the second circle the same way.