# How to draw the path of a rounded rectangle with optional border sides?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to draw a path for a rounded rectangle where the sides are optional.

The function would look like this:

```
function drawRoundRect(width, height, sides, topLeftRadius, topRightRadius, bottomLeftRadius, bottomRightRadius) {
    pathData = "M 0 0...";
}
```

But I can't figure out the path data.

The user would be able to say:

```
var myPath = drawRoundRect(100,100,"top left right", 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

and it would create a rectangle with three sides where the bottom line of the rectangle is not drawn.

Or for a full rectangle they would write this:

```
var myPath = drawRoundRect(100,100,"top left right bottom", 10, 10, 10, 10);

// top and bottom no rounded corners
var myPath = drawRoundRect(100,100,"top bottom", 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: literally the first result for searching "svg path rounded rectangle" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177985/svg-rounded-corner

Comment: Hi this is not a duplicate. That question has a function for rounding the corners of an existing path. My question is about creating a new path. Please do not mark this as duplicate

Comment: Hi this question is not a duplicate. Please reopen or I will post it again.