# SVG: How to animate a path's height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to create the rounded edges using `svg` `rect` tag. But `rx` and `ry` is making the rounded edges in four edges. Instead I'm trying to create only two edges (top left and top right). Same thing I have done with `path` command (Working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbdst0ms/)).

The reason of creating **rect** is I'm trying to create the animated grow height.

```
<rect x="50" y="0" fill="#f00" width="100" height="100">
    <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="100" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
</rect>
```

---

**EDITED**

The following code will give the rounded corner what I have expected. I have used Cubic Curve method.

```
<svg style="width:500px; height:800px;">
    <path class="draw" d="M 75 445 L75 116.66666666666669 C 80 91.66666666666669 120 91.66666666666669 125 116.66666666666669 L125 445 75 445" style="stroke: rgb(192, 31, 31); stroke-width: 2px; fill: rgb(216, 62, 62);"></path>
</svg>
```

My question/problem is when I create the animation in path, height is not growing with animation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177985/svg-rounded-corner

Comment: @Amit I have done this thing. Please check the Fiddle in my question. I'm trying to create the same thing using `rect` tag.

Comment: You can't use the rect tag for this. What's wrong with the path tag?

Comment: @RobertLongson The problem is I'm trying to animate the height like auto grow height. Thats why I'm moving to rect tag.

Comment: Why not ask that question about animating the path tag then!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG rounded corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177985/svg-rounded-corner)

Comment: @MohammadUsman Read the question, I'm asking to create the rounded corner in **RECT** tag not in path. I have done the rounded corner in path tag. My doubt is animate the height in svg path. If it is not possible, how to make the rounded corner in rect tag.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have edited my question.

Comment: @mkHun Do you wants to animate `height` from bottom to top or vice versa?

Comment: @MohammadUsman Exactly I'm trying to animate the height bottom to top.

Comment: @mkHun Is this what you want? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtc84nq6/)

Comment: @mkHun Even a simpler variant. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kexpme84/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CSS3's `scaleY()` transformation to create the desired animation.

Initially your `path` will have `scaleY(0)` value (it will behave like the element has `height: 0`) and we will animate it to `scaleY(1)`.

Following CSS will be required for this:

```
path {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation: draw 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```css
.draw {
  animation: draw 1.5s linear forwards;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  stroke: rgb(192, 31, 31);
  fill: rgb(216, 62, 62);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">
    <path class="draw"
          d="M 75 200 L75 25 C 80 0 120 0 125 25 L125 200 75 200" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;opacity:1" />
  <rect x="50" y="40" rx="0" ry="0" width="150" height="130" style="fill:red;opacity:1" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

This is little tricky and this will do the work.Its a sample so you can do the same with yours too.

Answer (score -1):

For rounded corners for only the top you can use this in css

```
border-top-left-radius
border-top-right-radius
```

**Here is an example below.**

```css
img{ width:100%;
height:100%;
border-top-left-radius:20px;
border-top-right-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://wallpaperswide.com/download/color_splash_effect-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg">
```

Comment: OP is asking about `SVG` not about `img` from `HTML`.