# border-radius with border-image

Tags: css, border, border-image

In following code I expect both divs to be round. But the first one with `border-image` applied is square. How can I fix that and make it round too?

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: auto;
  
  border: 30px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue) 30;
}

div + div {
  margin-left: 1em;
  border-image: none;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: a related one with dashed border in case you need it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60586691/8620333

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to combine them. The W3 Spec says:

> A box's backgrounds, but not its border-image, are clipped to the appropriate curve (as determined by ‘background-clip’). Other effects that clip to the border or padding edge (such as ‘overflow’ other than ‘visible’) also must clip to the curve. The content of replaced elements is always trimmed to the content edge curve. Also, the area outside the curve of the border edge does not accept mouse events on behalf of the element.

However, you can achieve the same effect by using a multiple elements and a CSS gradient

```css
#cont{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, crimson 0%, blue 100%);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#box{
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want a circle, just write `50%` in `border-radius` instead of writing enormous numbers in pixels.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) background-image. And you can mask it with [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image). `border-image` does not work with `border-radius`.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: auto;
  /* border: 30px solid transparent;
     border-radius: 50%;
    border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue) 30;*/
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(transparent 0 65px, #000 65.5px);
          mask-image: radial-gradient(transparent 0 65px, #000 65.5px);
}

div+div {
  margin-left: 1em;
  border-image: none;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: you can remove the `at 50% 50%` because it's already the default value

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks I removed