# How to create cut border gradient for button using CSS3

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, linear-gradients

I have to achieve the below look and feel using CSS gradient for button or any other suggestion also welcome

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ois9A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hovbq.png)

```html
<button class="button-demo">Call to action</button>
```

```css
.button-demo{
    
        padding:20px;
        border:5px solid;
        border-radius: 15px;
        //border-image:linear-gradient(60deg,#00a7e1 50%,#f6531d 0) 20;
        border-image: conic-gradient(red, transparent, yellow,transparent, red,transparent, yellow) 1;
        background:transparent;
    
}
```

Comment: border-radius and border-image don't work together. There's quite a lot about this and some workarounds if you search. For example take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052199/border-radius-with-border-image

Comment: is there way to achieve using css3 , please suggest really looking for the solutions
, i found one link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496204/border-gradient-with-border-radiusbut i am not getting how to keep space between two borders. TIA

Comment: What have you tried from the various suggestions given?

Comment: i was trying to achieve button border should have space between two colors

Comment: What have you tried from the several suggestions in the two references above?